# Spring Data JDBC QueryCreationException. Spring Data treating my custom query name as a property name

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

I'm writing a custom query with Spring Data JDBC:

```
public interface AuditRecordRepository extends CrudRepository<AuditRecord, Long> {

@Modifying
@Query("DELETE FROM audit_records ar WHERE ar.created_on <= :date;")
int retainDataBefore(@Param("date") Timestamp retainDate);

}
```

AuditRecord:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "audit_records")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AuditRecord {
  @Id 
  @Column(name="id")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "created_on")
  private Timestamp date;
}
```

When I run the application it says:

```
No property for "retainData" found for type "AuditRecord" found.
```

treating my method name as a property. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You verified you are using the JDBC versions of `@Modifying` and `@Query`, I assume? Can you make a reproducer available on GitHub?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out in the end. It was because I was using annotations with the same name but from incorrect packages. Sorry for such a simple mistake. I hope I didn't waste too much time for people who are trying to help.

Comment: Consider deleting the whole question. It is not useful for other future readers - it helped only to you :)

Answer (score 0):

By default, the query definition uses JPQL.

Then your query should be this:

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query("DELETE FROM AuditRecord ar WHERE ar.date = :date")
int retainDataBefore(@Param("date") Timestamp retainDate);
```

Otherwise you can use Native query:
Then your query should be this:

```
@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query(
        value = "DELETE FROM audit_records ar WHERE ar.created_on = :date",
        nativeQuery = true)
int retainDataBefore1(@Param("date") Timestamp retainDate);
```

**Note:** Please remove ";" inside your query. if you have definition **@Transactional**  in your service class then remove from repository interface.

Comment: But I'm using Spring Data JDBC (not JPA), it doesn't have JPQL suppport if I recall correctly.

Comment: In your above code is Spring Data JPA code, if you want to use Spring JDBC this case, should be use JdbcTemplate or  Named Parameters, please check this tutorial for Spring JDBC https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jdbc-jdbctemplate

Comment: @Herny These are three different things, Spring Data JPA, Spring Data JDBC and Spring JDBC. Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51923060/spring-jdbc-vs-spring-data-jdbc-and-what-are-they-supporting

Comment: @Izy917, yes, you have reason, however It is part of the larger Spring Data family of projects, which also includes Spring Data JPA, then you can use native query, thank you for your inputs.

Comment: Spring Data JDBC does not support JPQL nor does it have a way to distinguish _native_ from _non_native_ queries, since that concept does not apply.

Comment: @HenryXilojHerrera This one might be interesting as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42470060/spring-data-jdbc-spring-data-jpa-vs-hibernate/42488593

Comment: @Jens Schauder,  I read the post, now for me is clear, although, I created a basic project, Spring Jdbc, Spring Data JPA, Spring Data JDBC  for check the differences. thank you.